# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint on landing page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page

I'm getting **Violation of PRIMARY KEY** constraint when submitting a email address on a landing page. all I am doing is capturing the email address. the data extension is sendable and only contains the email address which is set as the PK. is there a way to check if the email already exists in the data extension.

CODE: `SET @Response = InsertDE("DE", "EmailAddress", @EmailAddress)`

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

updated to upsertDE and it worked